# how to implement shadertoy itime?

Tags: android, shader

https://www.shadertoy.com/
I want to implement `shadertoy` `itime` in my android studio project, I want to implement `itime` var in my project,
this is my code:

```
    long last_time = System.nanoTime();

while(running) {
    long time = System.nanoTime();
    int delta_time = (int) ((time - last_time) / 1000000);
    last_time = time;
}
```

but this doesn't work, are there other ways to implement `itime` in android?

Answer (score 2):

iTime is a elapsed time value.
 Making `last_time = time` will only tell you the time **between** each loop. Wherease `iTime` is the time since the begining of your program or a defined periode in time.
So just remove `last_time = time` and make your `delta_time` variable a `long` or `double` and be sure to rename it or it will be confusing for you in the futur!
If you decide to make your `delta_time` a :`double` be sure to divide by 1 000 000 000 instead of 1 000 000, you will have the second on the left part and the millisecond on the right part like in shadertoy.

in shadertoy there are to define variable for time :

- **uniform float iTime** : tell the time as said before
- **uniform float iTimeDelta** : tell the time between each frame

if you want to know more check out the [how to](https://www.shadertoy.com/howto) on there website !